# making GridView row selectable by clicking anywhere on the row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I need to have a GridView row selectable by clicking anywhere on the row. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have added the Grid manually from the Tools bar you can change its `Selection Mode` property to `FullRowSelect`. If you have added it programmatically you can use

`Grid.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect`.

`Grid.Rows[Grid.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["nameofcolumn"].Value.ToString()`

- provided your DataGridView is called "Grid". This will display the content of a particular cell.